# Adobe Illustrator CC Transparent inside vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, pen-tool

So i have trace a logo using pen tool the problem is the logo has a hole inside that I need it to be transparent. Here is the look of the image [link](http://prntscr.com/5aler8)

now I need to make the white inside the logo transparent but when I change the fill to none the look will be [this](http://prntscr.com/5alfun)

what should I do about this? I just started with Illustrator.

Comment: It would be nice if you can upload that .ai file so that others can take a look and solve you problem.

Comment: Possibly Helpful: [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20648/making-parts-of-illustrator-logo-transparent-rather-than-faking-it-with-the-ba?rq=1), [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37423/combining-and-layering-transparent-shapes-in-illustrator?rq=1), and [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7212/how-do-i-delete-the-center-of-the-letter-a-in-adobe-illustrator-cs5/7214#7214)

Answer (score 0):

you should subtract the holes so it will appears transparent. you can do that by selecting the three objects and go to the menu Windows >Pathfinder > and select the Exclude icon.

That's it.

please notice that the very top object will cut the lower.

Comment: doing that makes the black all white inside the outline.

Comment: I used Minus instead of unite and exclude

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the object and remove compund path.You will get the exact shape like the hole.Make it white or just subtract.Both will do.